# Problem about socket communication

Tags: c#, sockets

I have two separate socket projects in VS.NET. One of them is sender, other one is receiver. After starting receiver, i send data from sender. Although send method returns 13 bytes as successfully transferred, the receiver receives 0 (zero). The receiver accepts sender socket and listens to it. But cannot receive data. Why?

P.S. : If sender code is put in receiver project, receiver can get data, as well.

Comment: Need to see more code, how are you establishing the connection and sending data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the send application is ending before the receiver can read the data.  If you put a `Thread.Sleep(1000);` after the `Send` call, the receive application will read the data (at least when I tested it).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a bug in your code but without seeing the code it's impossible to tell.

However be aware that TCP/IP has no concept of messages, only a stream of data. So it's posisble to send 13 bytes and receive 6 in one read and 7 in the next. Or conversely to send 13 bytes then later send 7 more and on the receiveing side to receive them as a single block of 20 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your interest.
Here is the code:

/*********************************** Receiver **********************/

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Receiver recv = new Receiver();
            recv.Start();
        }
    }

```
public class Receiver
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Socket gateSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        gateSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8999));
        gateSocket.Listen(12);

        Thread thGateListen = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(GateListener));
        thGateListen.Start(gateSocket);
    }

    public void GateListener(object obj)
    {

        Socket gateSocket = (Socket)obj;

        for (; ; )
        {
            Socket newRequest = gateSocket.Accept();
            Console.WriteLine("New Connection Request");
            Thread thReadData = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ReadFromSocket));
            thReadData.Start(newRequest);
        }
    }


    public void ReadFromSocket(object obj)
    {
        Socket s = (Socket)obj;
        for (; ; )
        {
            if (s.Available > 0)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[s.Available];
                s.Receive(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

/*********************************** Sender **********************/

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Sender s = new Sender();
            s.Send("Hello Socket!");
        }
    }

```
class Sender
{
    public void Send(string s)
    {
        Socket sendSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sendSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8999));

        sendSocket.Send(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can't only one process open a port on the machine?

Comment: I think sender program is terminated before Receiver  program receives the data. Put some sleep after send() in sender program and see it works.